Aerospike BatchRead Api find source/originating Set for records in response
Aerospike Batch read api takes an array of sets as input like this:
        final Key[] keys1 = new Key[3];
        keys1[0] = new Key(config.getNamespace(), config.getSetName(1)), key);
        keys1[1] = new Key(config.getNamespace(), config.getSetName(2)), key);
        keys1[2] = new Key(config.getNamespace(), config.getSetName(3)), key);

And returns response as a array of records (Record[3]), with elements from the same set in the recordList in correct order if all 3 sets contain the key.
If one of the sets doesn't have the key present, then I get a response as Record[2] and no way to tie the elements to the originating set.
Is there a way around this? My sets are grouped hourly/daily. I want to make only one call to aerospike, and be able to distinguish data between sets.
I don't want to make composite keys(huge no. of keys: 10^9) and also cannot make multiple namespaces due to the query presumably becoming expensive.

Could you share the code which shows the batch call? The expectation is that you would get a records[3] response for a keys[3] input. Failed gets would appear as null in the response array.

I noted you requested me to comment. I modeled your problem in Jupyter Notebook. Let me post the relevant code segments. As @kporter said, for records not present, it returns null.
Key key1 = new Key("test", "testSet1", 1); 
Key key2 = new Key("test", "testSet2", 2);  // We will not create this record 
Key key3 = new Key("test", "testSet3", 3); 
Key key4 = new Key("test", "testSet4", 4);
Bin b1 = new Bin("bin1", 100);
Bin b2 = new Bin("bin1", 200);
Bin b3 = new Bin("bin1", 300);
Bin b4 = new Bin("bin1", 400);
client.put(null, key1, b1);
//client.put(null, key2, b2); //Skipping so its a null record
client.put(null, key3, b3);
client.put(null, key4, b4);

This creates 3 records at keys key1, key3 and key4. Now lets do a batch read:
BatchPolicy batchPolicy = new BatchPolicy();    
Record [] bReads = client.get(batchPolicy, new Key[] {key1, key2, key3, key4});    
// process the batch reads
for (int i = 0; i < bReads.length; i++) {
    Record bRead = bReads[i];    
    if (bRead != null) {          // check individual record
        long bin1Val = bRead.getLong("bin1");         
        System.out.format("Result[%d]: bin1: %d\n",i, bin1Val);
    }
    else {   // error in individual key's operations
        System.out.format("Result[%d]: not found: \n", i);
    }
}

Output is:
Result[0]: bin1: 100
Result[1]: not found: 
Result[2]: bin1: 300
Result[3]: bin1: 400


Tried multiple times, this is the first thing I tried. Pretty sure it doesn't, atleast in version 6.0. Which version are you using?

I am using the latest E-7.0.0.8 and Java Client 7.2.1 but should work the same with server version 6.0.  Not sure pre 6.0 - BatchPolicy.respondAllKeys should be true (default) - which anyway ignores key-not-found error and so should work even with false to find null records.

I had another setup running E-6.2.0.7 server and Java Client 6.0.0 - worked there too, same as above.

Trust you are staying under the 1023 max set names limit for your server version. (In 7.0 server, it increased to max 4095 sets.)

Found that we were using a custom response wrapper that was removing null values in response.

Mystery solved! Thanks for reverting back.
